# An interesting limit: $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin 1\sin\sqrt{1}+\sin 2\sin\sqrt{2}+\sin 3\sin\sqrt{3}+\cdots+\sin n\sin\sqrt{n}}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I would like to prove that

$$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin 1\sin\sqrt{1}+\sin 2\sin\sqrt{2}+\sin 3\sin\sqrt{3}+\cdots+\sin n\sin\sqrt{n}}{n}=0$$

but I am stuck.

I tried to solve it by using [Euler-Maclaurin formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula), but I could not to.

Euler-Maclaurin formula applied to the function $f(x)=\sin x \sin\sqrt{x}\;\;$ is the following:

$$\sum_{h=1}^n\sin h\sin\sqrt{h}=\int_\limits{0}^n\left[\sin x\sin\sqrt{x}+\left(x-\lfloor x\rfloor\right)\left(\cos x\sin\sqrt{x}+\frac{\sin x\cos\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{x}}\right)\right] \, dx$$

but I could not manage to prove that

$$\frac{1}{n}\int_\limits{0}^n\left(x-\lfloor x\rfloor\right)\left(\cos x \sin\sqrt{x} \right) \, dx\rightarrow 0 \text{ as } n\to\infty.$$

Moreover I tried to write the limit as a limit of a Riemann sum, but I did not manage to.

Furthermore I tried to prove the following inequality:

$$\left|\sin 1\sin\sqrt{1}+\sin 2\sin\sqrt{2}+\cdots+\sin n \sin\sqrt{n} \right|\le\sqrt[4]{n^3}\\\text{for all }\;n\in\mathbb{N},$$

but it was not successful.

I managed to prove that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin 1+\sin 2 +\sin 3+\ldots+\sin n}{n}=0$$

and

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin\sqrt{1}+\sin\sqrt{2}+\sin\sqrt{3}+\cdots+\sin\sqrt{n}}{n}=0.$$

Is it possible to use these last two limits in order to prove that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin 1\sin\sqrt{1}+\sin 2\sin\sqrt{2}+\sin 3 \sin\sqrt{3}+\cdots+\sin n\sin\sqrt{n}}{n}=0\text{ ?}$$

I tried to use Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, but I got $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin^21+\sin^22+\cdots+\sin^2n}{n}$$ and $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin^2\sqrt{1}+\sin^2\sqrt{2}+\cdots+\sin^2\sqrt{n}}{n}$$ and these last two limits are not zero in fact there are both $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Yes, I know it but how can I prove that the limit is zero formally and rigorously?

Comment: @NamburuKarthik we have to prove it, not speculate an answer

Comment: And i think you'd like to use Cauchy-Schwartz inequality in your last two equations, it would be sufficient

Comment: If you use Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, you get $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin^21+\sin^22+\ldots+\sin^2n}{n}$ and $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin^2\sqrt{1}+\sin^2\sqrt{2}+\ldots+\sin^2\sqrt{n}}{n}$, but these last two limits are not zero in fact there are both $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: why not $n^2$??

Comment: Because you have to apply Cauchy-Schwartz inequality to the numerators otherwise you would get $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin 1\sin\sqrt{1}+\sin 2\sin\sqrt{2}+\ldots+\sin n\sin\sqrt{n}}{n^2}$ which is not the limit I wish to.

Comment: My suggestion is to seperate into to 2 sums $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\cos(1+\sqrt{1})+\cos(2+\sqrt{2})+...+\cos(n+\sqrt{n})}{n}$ and  $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\cos(1-\sqrt{1})+\cos(2-\sqrt{2})+...+\cos(n-\sqrt{n})}{n}$. Each sum should be 0 by very similar process.

Comment: I have already applied Euler-Maclaurin formula to that two limits but it was not successful. I found the same difficulties I got when I applied Euler-Maclaurin formula to my limit.

Comment: @Mark, please can you explain me why $\frac{1}{n}\int_\limits{0}^n\left(x-\lfloor x\rfloor\right)\left(\cos x\sin\sqrt{x}\right)dx\rightarrow 0$ as $n\to\infty$ ?

Comment: Look at this https://i.stack.imgur.com/zn0eA.png. So “desmos” give us a confirmation that $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin 1\sin\sqrt{1}+\sin 2\sin\sqrt{2}+\sin 3\sin\sqrt{3}+\ldots+\sin n\sin\sqrt{n}}{n}=0$

Comment: You can also try to use **Weyl's (Equidistributed) criterion** in some way.

Comment: Weyl’s equidistributed criterion does not work in this case in fact $\int_0^{2\pi} \sin x\sin\sqrt{x} dx \ne 0$ and $\int_0^{1}\sin x\sin\sqrt{x} dx \ne 0$.

Comment: @NamburuKarthik: this reasoning is flawed. "Nearly as many" can be sufficient to create an imbalance.

Comment: Expressions of form "sin asin b are ambiguous, and math notation is not consistent. For example, we all know sin 2x is sin(2x) and not (sin 2)x. But then, why should we assume a more complex expression such as sin asin b is (sin a)(sin b) and not sin(a sinb)? The latter would be more consistent with the sin(2x) situation.

Sorry about being overly pedantic or priggish (priggish?), but it is for this situation that I ALWAYS use proper functional notation with sin(x) -- NEVER "sin x".

Comment: @Angelo Was there a reason for reversing your accepting my solution?

Answer (score 17):

Let $S_n$ be given by

$$S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(k)\sin\sqrt{k}\tag1$$

Applying summation by parts to the sum in $(1)$ reveals

$$S_n=\sin(\sqrt {n+1})\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin(k)-\sum_{k=1}^n \left(\sum_{\ell=1}^k \sin(\ell)\right)\left(\sin(\sqrt {k+1})-\sin(\sqrt{k})\right)\tag 2$$

---

**ESTIMATES:**

The sum $\sum_{\ell=1}^k \sin(\ell)$ can be evaluated in closed form which provides the estimate

$$\begin{align}
\left|\sum_{\ell=1}^n \sin(\ell)\right|&=\left|\csc(1/2)\sin(n/2)\sin((n+1)/2)\right|\\\\
\le \csc(1/2)\tag3
\end{align}$$

Moreover, from the [Prosthaphaeresis identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosthaphaeresis#Reverse_identities), we have the estimate

$$\begin{align}
\left|\sin(\sqrt {k+1})-\sin(\sqrt{k}\right|&=\left|\frac12\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}}{2}\right)\right|\\\\
&=\left|2\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{1}{2(\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k})}\right)\right|\\\\
&\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\tag4
\end{align}$$

---

Using the estimates in $(3)$ and $(4)$ in $(2)$, we find that

$$\begin{align}
|S_n|&\le \csc(1/2)\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt k}\right)\\\\
&\le \csc(1/2)(1+2\sqrt n)\tag5
\end{align}$$

---

Finally, using the estimate in $(5)$ we have

$$\left|\frac{S_n}{n}\right|\le \frac{\csc(1/2)(1+2\sqrt n)}{n}$$

whence application of the squeeze theorem recovers the coveted limit

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n \sin(k)\sin(\sqrt k)}{n}=0}$$

---

**NOTE:  We have tacitly found that $$\limsup_{n\to \infty}\frac{S_n}{\sqrt n}\le 2\csc(1/2)$$**

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate why the difference between $S_n$ and the integral is $o(1)$? btw, I assume $o(1) ~ O(1/n)$?

Comment: Could you explain me why $\frac{1}{n}\int_0^n\left(x-\lfloor x\rfloor\right)\left(\cos x\sin\sqrt{x}+\frac{\sin x\cos\sqrt{x}}{2\sqrt{x}}\right)dx$ is $o(1)$?

Comment: @Angelo Rather than elaborate on the former solution, I've taken another approach.  This new approach relies only on summation by parts and some simple estimates.  Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Nice solution too - uses the estimate on the  square root only which indeed is simpler and that is enough here (basically the $\sin n$ coefficients can be any $a_n$ with uniformly bounded sum and your solution works with a square root bound while use that $x$ dominated $\sqrt x$ essentially but get a better bound

Comment: Thanks Conrad!  And I hope that you and your family are staying safe and healthy.

Comment: Actually you have tacitly found that $\limsup_\limits{n\to \infty}\frac{|S_n|}{\sqrt n}\le2\csc(1/2)$.

Comment: @Angelo Indeed.  Thank you for the catch.  I've edited the typographical error accordingly.

Comment: @Angelo Interestingly, empirical analysis seems to indicate that $-0.31\le 
\sum_{n=1}^N \sin(n)\sin(\sqrt n)\le 1.8$.

Comment: Yes, indeed the constant found by Conrad could be improved further.

Comment: @Angelo Was there a reason for reversing your accepting my solution?

Answer (score 4):

One can actually say more and show that:

$|\sin 1\sin\sqrt{1}+\sin 2\sin\sqrt{2}+\ldots+\sin n\sin\sqrt{n}| \le C$ for some universal constant.

Using the sine product formula, it is enough to prove the result for

$$C_1(n)=\cos(1+\sqrt{1})+\cos(2+\sqrt{2})+\cdots+\cos(n+\sqrt{n})$$ and

$$C_2(n)=\cos(1-\sqrt{1})+\cos(2-\sqrt{2})+\cdots+\cos(n-\sqrt{n})$$

and then taking real parts it is enough to show the result for

$$S_{1,2}(n)=\sum_{k=1}^ne^{i(k\pm\sqrt k)}$$

We will show that $|S_{1,2}| \le C$ for a universal constant $C$ so the result will follow and we will do the proof for $S_2$ indicating the estimate changes needed for $S_1$ which are minor.

Let $g(x)=\frac{x-\sqrt x}{2 \pi}, x \ge 1$ and note that $1/(4\pi) \le g'(x) \le 1/(2\pi)$ and this inequality is enough to prove our result (the fact that the lower and upper bounds are constants strictly between $0$ and $1$.

Note also that by omitting a fixed finite number of terms which we can bound trivially the result holds for functions $f(x)$ like $3x+100\sqrt x, -2x+x^{1-1/10000}$ and so on, the crucial part being that $g'(x)=f'(x)/(2\pi)=c+o(1), x \to \infty, c \ne 0, |c| <1$, so $0<c_1<|g'(x)|<c_2<1, x >k$ for constants $c_1,c_2,k$ and for the function $h$ involved in $S_1$ we have $1/(2\pi) \le |h'(x)| \le 3/(4\pi)$

Let $q(n)=g(n+1)-g(n), n \ge 1$ so by the MVT there is $n \le x_n \le n+1, q(n)=g'(x_n)$ In particular $q_n$ increasing since $g'$ does (if $g'$ would be decreasing like for $S_1$ we conjugate and replace $g$ by $-g$) and $1/(4\pi)  \le q(n) \le 1/(2\pi)$

But now the identity:

$$e^{2\pi i g(k)}=1/2(1+i\cot \pi q(k))(e^{2\pi i g(k)}-e^{2\pi i g(k+1)})$$ gives that

$$S_2(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}e^{2\pi i g(k)}=\sum_1^{n}1/2(1+i\cot \pi q(k))(e^{2\pi i g(k)}-e^{2\pi i g(k+1)})=$$

$$=i/2\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}e^{2\pi i g(k)}(\cot \pi q(k)-\cot \pi q(k+1))+1/2(1+i\cot \pi q(1))e^{2\pi i g(1)}-(1/2)(1+i\cot \pi q(n))e^{2\pi i g(n+1)}$$

by rearranging the terms and noting that only terms with $g(1), g(n+1)$ appear only once

But now taking absolute values and noting that $\cot \pi q(k)-\cot \pi q(k+1)$ is decreasing since $1/4<\pi q(k) <1/2<\pi, q(k)$ increasing, we get:

$$|S_2(n)| \le 1/2 (\cot \pi q(2)-\cot \pi q(n))+1/2(|\cot \pi q(n)|+|\cot \pi q(1)|+1 \le C_2 $$ where $C_2$ is obtained by using that all the cotangtents above are at most $\cot 1/4$, so one can take $C_2=2\cot 1/4 +1$ for example and clearly we get a similar $C_1$ for $S_1$ so we are done!

Comment: Why have you written $1/(4\pi) \le g'(x) \le 1/(2\pi)$ ? I think that $1/(2\pi) \le g'(x) \le 3/(4\pi)$, am I wrong?

Comment: $g’(x)$ is decreasing and if we replace $g(x)$ by $-g(x)$ then $-\frac{3}{4\pi}\le q(n)\le -\frac{1}{2\pi}$ and $e^{i(k+\sqrt{k})}=e^{-2\pi i g(k)}$.

Comment: @conrad Nice solution.  I've posted another one that relies only on summation by parts and some simple estimates.  Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: You are right - I switched the estimates, will correct

Comment: @Conrad, you wrote that

$$S_2(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}e^{2\pi i g(k)}=\sum_1^{n}1/2(1+i\cot \pi q(k))(e^{2\pi i g(k)}-e^{2\pi i g(k+1)})=$$

$$=i/2\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}e^{2\pi i g(k)}(\cot \pi q(k)-\cot \pi q(k+1))+1/2(1+i\cot \pi q(1))e^{2\pi i g(1)}-(1/2)(1+i\cot \pi q(n))e^{2\pi i g(n+1)}$$

but I have obtained that

$$S_2(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}e^{2\pi i g(k)}=\sum_1^{n}1/2(1+i\cot \pi q(k))(e^{2\pi i g(k)}-e^{2\pi i g(k+1)})=$$

$$=i/2\sum_{k=2}^{n} e^{2\pi i g(k)}(\cot \pi q(k)-\cot \pi q(k-1))+1/2(1+i\cot \pi q(1))e^{2\pi i g(1)}-1/2(1+i\cot \pi q(n))e^{2\pi i g(n+1)}$$

Comment: Please, could you check what I have obtained ?

Comment: Since $\;0<\cot \pi q(n)\le \cot 1/4,\;$ we get that

$$|S_2(n)| \le 1/2 (\cot \pi q(2)-\cot \pi q(n))+1/2(|\cot \pi q(n)|+|\cot \pi q(1)|)+1= 1/2 (\cot \pi q(2)+\cot \pi q(1))+1\le \cot 1/4 +1$$

Is it right?

Comment: looks good at a glance - the whole point is that $0< c_1 \le |g'(x)| \le c_2 <1, g'$ monotonic - then the estimates are in terms of $c_1,c_2$ and can be tightened somewhat if that is important; note that even if $c_1, c_2$ depend on $n$ one can get estimates but they won't be $O(1)$ anymore, though they may beat the trivial estimate $N$ at least in some ranges, so it's useful to know this method - one can also apply it on sections where one has control of $g'$ (so $g'$ is never an integer - by $k$ translation that is equivalent to the above -) and combine it with other methods

Comment: Your method is very good, I thank you for your help. I just have to correct some calculations’ mistakes but your method does work very well. Thank you very much. I will try to write a proof without using complex numbers.

Comment: By using your method is also possible to prove that $\left|\sum_\limits{k=1}^n \cos(\sqrt{k})\right|\le 4\sqrt{n+1}+2$.

Comment: yes one can do that  - though this is (an adaptation of) Mordell's proof of the Kuzmin Landau inequality (a short icm presentation is here as a pdf file) https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiOlYW2u5jrAhUHAp0JHdSJAzoQFjAAegQIBRAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmatwbn.icm.edu.pl%2Fksiazki%2Faa%2Faa4%2Faa412.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1nJmBQh8GD3RCqoRdaPqD9

Answer (score 2):

**Property 1:**

If $\;\left\{a_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\;$ is a sequence of real numbers such that $\;\left\{a_n-a_{n-1}\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}}\;$ is monotonic and there exists $\;k\in\mathbb{Z}\;$ for which $\;2\pi k<a_n-a_{n-1}<2\pi+2\pi k\;\;\;\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}\;,\;\;\;$ then $$\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n \cos a_h\right|\le\frac{1}{2}\left[\;\left|\cot\left(\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{2}\right)-\cot\left(\frac{a_2-a_1}{2}\right)\right|+\\+\left|\cot\left(\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{2}\right)\right|+|\sin a_1|\left|\cot\left(\frac{a_2-a_1}{2}\right)\right|+\\+|\cos a_1|+1\;\right]$$ for all $\;n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}.$

**Proof:**

By applying Prosthaphaeresis identities, we get that

$\cos a_h+\cos a_{h+1}=2\cos\left(\frac{a_{h+1}+a_h}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{a_{h+1}-a_h}{2}\right)=\\=2\cos\left(\frac{a_{h+1}+a_h}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{a_{h+1}-a_h}{2}\right)\cot\left(\frac{a_{h+1}-a_h}{2}\right)=\\=\left(\sin a_{h+1}-\sin a_h\right)\cot\left(\frac{a_{h+1}-a_h}{2}\right)\;,\;\;\text{ for all }h\in\mathbb{N}.$

Moreover,

$2\sum_\limits{h=1}^n\cos a_h=\sum_\limits{h=1}^{n-1}\left(\cos a_h +\cos a_{h+1}\right)+\cos a_1+\cos a_n=\\=\sum_\limits{h=1}^{n-1}\left(\sin a_{h+1}-\sin a_h\right)\cot\left(\frac{a_{h+1}-a_h}{2}\right)+\cos a_1+\cos a_n =\\=\sum_\limits{h=1}^{n-1}\sin a_{h+1}\cot\left(\frac{a_{h+1}-a_h}{2}\right)-\sum_\limits{h=1}^{n-1}\sin a_h\cot\left(\frac{a_{h+1}-a_h}{2}\right)+\\+\cos a_1+\cos a_n=\\=\sum_\limits{h=2}^{n}\sin a_h\cot\left(\frac{a_h-a_{h-1}}{2}\right)-\sum_\limits{h=1}^{n-1}\sin a_h\cot\left(\frac{a_{h+1}-a_h}{2}\right)+\\+\cos a_1+\cos a_n =\\=\sum_\limits{h=2}^{n-1}\sin a_h\left[\cot\left(\frac{a_h-a_{h-1}}{2}\right)-\cot\left(\frac{a_{h+1}-a_h}{2}\right)\right]+\\+\sin a_n\cot\left(\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{2}\right)-\sin a_1\cot\left(\frac{a_2-a_1}{2}\right)+\cos a_1+\cos a_n\;,\\\text{ for all }\;n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}.$

Since the function $\;\cot\;$ is monotonic on $\;\left]\pi k,\pi+\pi k\right[\;$ and $\;\left\{a_n-a_{n-1}\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}}\;$ is a monotonic sequence such that $\;2\pi k<a_n-a_{n-1}<2\pi+2\pi k\;\;\;\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}\;,\;$ then the sequence $\;\left\{\cot\left(\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{2}\right)\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}}\;$ is monotonic too.

So by taking absolute values and by noting that the sequence $\;\left\{\cot\left(\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{2}\right)\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}}\;$ is monotonic, we get that

$2\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n\cos a_h\right|\le\sum_\limits{h=2}^{n-1}\left|\cot\left(\frac{a_h-a_{h-1}}{2}\right)-\cot\left(\frac{a_{h+1}-a_h}{2}\right)\right|+\\+\left|\cot\left(\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{2}\right)\right|+|\sin a_1|\left|\cot\left(\frac{a_2-a_1}{2}\right)\right|+|\cos a_1|+1=\\=\left|\cot\left(\frac{a_2-a_1}{2}\right)-\cot\left(\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{2}\right)\right|+\left|\cot\left(\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{2}\right)\right|+\\+|\sin a_1|\left|\cot\left(\frac{a_2-a_1}{2}\right)\right|+|\cos a_1|+1=\\=\left|\cot\left(\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{2}\right)-\cot\left(\frac{a_2-a_1}{2}\right)\right|+\left|\cot\left(\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{2}\right)\right|+\\+|\sin a_1|\left|\cot\left(\frac{a_2-a_1}{2}\right)\right|+|\cos a_1|+1\;,$

for all $\;n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}.$

---

**Property 2:**

If $\;\left\{a_n\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\;$ is a sequence of real numbers such that $\;\left\{a_n-a_{n-1}\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}}\;$ is monotonic and there exists $\;k\in\mathbb{Z}\;$ for which $\;2\pi k<a_n-a_{n-1}<2\pi+2\pi k\;\;\;\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}\;,\;\;\;$ then $$\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n \sin a_h\right|\le\frac{1}{2}\left[\; \left|\cot\left(\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{2}\right)-\cot\left(\frac{a_2-a_1}{2}\right)\right|+\\+\left|\cot\left(\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{2}\right)\right|+|\cos a_1|\left|\cot\left(\frac{a_2-a_1}{2}\right)\right|+\\+|\sin a_1|+1\;\right]$$ for all $\;n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}.$

**Proof:**

By applying Prosthaphaeresis identities, we get that

$\sin a_h+\sin a_{h+1}=2\sin\left(\frac{a_{h+1}+a_h}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{a_{h+1}-a_h}{2}\right)=\\=2\sin\left(\frac{a_{h+1}+a_h}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{a_{h+1}-a_h}{2}\right)\cot\left(\frac{a_{h+1}-a_h}{2}\right)=\\=\left(\cos a_h-\cos a_{h+1}\right)\cot\left(\frac{a_{h+1}-a_h}{2}\right)\;,\;\;\text{ for all }h\in\mathbb{N}.$

Moreover,

$2\sum_\limits{h=1}^n\sin a_h=\sum_\limits{h=1}^{n-1}\left(\sin a_h +\sin a_{h+1}\right)+\sin a_1+\sin a_n=\\=\sum_\limits{h=1}^{n-1}\left(\cos a_h-\cos a_{h+1}\right)\cot\left(\frac{a_{h+1}-a_h}{2}\right)+\sin a_1+\sin a_n =\\=\sum_\limits{h=1}^{n-1}\cos a_h\cot\left(\frac{a_{h+1}-a_h}{2}\right)-\sum_\limits{h=1}^{n-1}\cos a_{h+1}\cot\left(\frac{a_{h+1}-a_h}{2}\right)+\\+\sin a_1+\sin a_n=\\=\sum_\limits{h=1}^{n-1}\cos a_h\cot\left(\frac{a_{h+1}-a_h}{2}\right)-\sum_\limits{h=2}^n\cos a_h\cot\left(\frac{a_h-a_{h-1}}{2}\right)+\\+\sin a_1+\sin a_n =\\=\sum_\limits{h=2}^{n-1}\cos a_h\left[\cot\left(\frac{a_{h+1}-a_h}{2}\right)-\cot\left(\frac{a_h-a_{h-1}}{2}\right)\right]+\\+\cos a_1\cot\left(\frac{a_2-a_1}{2}\right)-\cos a_n\cot\left(\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{2}\right)+\sin a_1+\sin a_n\;,\\\text{ for all }\;n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}.$

Since the function $\;\cot\;$ is monotonic on $\;\left]\pi k,\pi+\pi k\right[\;$ and $\;\left\{a_n-a_{n-1}\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}}\;$ is a monotonic sequence such that $\;2\pi k<a_n-a_{n-1}<2\pi+2\pi k\;\;\;\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}\;,\;$ then the sequence $\;\left\{\cot\left(\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{2}\right)\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}}\;$ is monotonic too.

So by taking absolute values and by noting that the sequence $\;\left\{\cot\left(\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{2}\right)\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}}\;$ is monotonic, we get that

$2\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n\sin a_h\right|\le\sum_\limits{h=2}^{n-1}\left|\cot\left(\frac{a_{h+1}-a_h}{2}\right)-\cot\left(\frac{a_h-a_{h-1}}{2}\right)\right|+\\+|\cos a_1|\left|\cot\left(\frac{a_2-a_1}{2}\right)\right|+\left|\cot\left(\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{2}\right)\right|+|\sin a_1|+1=\\=\left|\cot\left(\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{2}\right)-\cot\left(\frac{a_2-a_1}{2}\right)\right|+\left|\cot\left(\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{2}\right)\right|+\\+|\cos a_1|\left|\cot\left(\frac{a_2-a_1}{2}\right)\right|+|\sin a_1|+1\;,$

for all $\;n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}.$

---

**Corollary 1:**

The sequences $\;\left\{\alpha_n=n+\sqrt{n}\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\;$ and $\left\{\beta_n=n-\sqrt{n}\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\;$ satisfy all the hypothesis of the previous properties and

$\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n \cos\left(h+\sqrt{h}\right)\right|<\frac{5}{2}\;,\;\;\text{ for all }\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;,$

$\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n \sin\left(h+\sqrt{h}\right)\right|<\frac{5}{2}\;,\;\;\text{ for all }\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;,$

$\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n \cos\left(h-\sqrt{h}\right)\right|<\frac{8}{3}\;,\;\;\text{ for all }\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;,$

$\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n \sin\left(h-\sqrt{h}\right)\right|<\frac{23}{6}\;,\;\;\text{ for all }\;n\in\mathbb{N}.$

**Proof:**

$\alpha_n-\alpha_{n-1}=n+\sqrt{n}-n+1-\sqrt{n-1}=\\=1+\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{n-1}=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}}\;,\\\text{for all }\;n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}.$

Hence the sequence $\;\left\{\alpha_n-\alpha_{n-1}\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}}\;$ is monotonically decreasing and $\;0<1<\alpha_n-\alpha_{n-1}\le\sqrt{2}<\pi<2\pi\;,$

$\text{for all }\;n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}.$

Since the function $\;\cot\;$ is monotonically decreasing on $\;\left]0,\pi\right[\;$ and $\;\left\{\alpha_n-\alpha_{n-1}\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}}\;$ is a decreasing sequence such that $\;0<\alpha_n-\alpha_{n-1}<2\pi\;\;\;\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}\;,\;$ then the sequence $\;\left\{\cot\left(\frac{\alpha_n-\alpha_{n-1}}{2}\right)\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}}\;$ is monotonically increasing.

By applying the property $1$, we get that

$\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n \cos\alpha_h\right|\le\frac{1}{2}\left[\;\left|\cot\left(\frac{\alpha_n-\alpha_{n-1}}{2}\right)-\cot\left(\frac{\alpha_2-\alpha_1}{2}\right)\right|+\\+\left|\cot\left(\frac{\alpha_n-\alpha_{n-1}}{2}\right)\right|+|\sin \alpha_1|\left|\cot\left(\frac{\alpha_2-\alpha_1}{2}\right)\right|+|\cos\alpha_1|+1\;\right]=\\=\frac{1}{2}\left[\;\cot\left(\frac{\alpha_n-\alpha_{n-1}}{2}\right)-\cot\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)+\\+\cot\left(\frac{\alpha_n-\alpha_{n-1}}{2}\right)+\sin 2\cot\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)-\cos 2+1\;\right]=\\=\cot\left(\frac{\alpha_n-\alpha_{n-1}}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\sin 2-1\right)\cot\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\cos 2\right)<\\<\cot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(\sin 2-1\right)\cot\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\cos 2\right)<\frac{5}{2}\;,$

for all $\;n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}.$

Therefore,

$\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n \cos\left(h+\sqrt{h}\right)\right|<\frac{5}{2}\;,\;\;\text{ for all }\;n\in\mathbb{N}.$

And by applying the property $2$, we get that

$\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n \sin\alpha_h\right|\le\frac{1}{2}\left[\;\left|\cot\left(\frac{\alpha_n-\alpha_{n-1}}{2}\right)-\cot\left(\frac{\alpha_2-\alpha_1}{2}\right)\right|+\\+\left|\cot\left(\frac{\alpha_n-\alpha_{n-1}}{2}\right)\right|+|\cos \alpha_1|\left|\cot\left(\frac{\alpha_2-\alpha_1}{2}\right)\right|+|\sin\alpha_1|+1\;\right]=\\=\frac{1}{2}\left[\;\cot\left(\frac{\alpha_n-\alpha_{n-1}}{2}\right)-\cot\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)+\\+\cot\left(\frac{\alpha_n-\alpha_{n-1}}{2}\right)-\cos 2\cot\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)+\sin 2+1\;\right]=\\=\cot\left(\frac{\alpha_n-\alpha_{n-1}}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\cos 2\right)\cot\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\sin 2\right)<\\<\cot\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\cos 2\right)\cot\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(1+\sin 2\right)<\frac{5}{2}\;,$

for all $\;n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}.$

Therefore,

$\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n \sin\left(h+\sqrt{h}\right)\right|<\frac{5}{2}\;,\;\;\text{ for all }\;n\in\mathbb{N}.$

Moreover,

$\beta_n-\beta_{n-1}=n-\sqrt{n}-n+1+\sqrt{n-1}=\\=1-\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}}\;,\\\text{for all }\;n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}.$

Hence the sequence $\;\left\{\beta_n-\beta_{n-1}\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}}\;$ is monotonically increasing and $\;0<2-\sqrt{2}\le\beta_n-\beta_{n-1}<1<\pi<2\pi\;,$

$\text{for all }\;n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}.$

Since the function $\;\cot\;$ is monotonically decreasing on $\;\left]0,\pi\right[\;$ and $\;\left\{\beta_n-\beta_{n-1}\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}}\;$ is an increasing sequence such that $\;0<\beta_n-\beta_{n-1}<2\pi\;\;\;\;\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}\;,\;$ then the sequence $\;\left\{\cot\left(\frac{\beta_n-\beta_{n-1}}{2}\right)\right\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}}\;$ is monotonically decreasing.

By applying the property $1$, we get that

$\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n \cos\beta_h\right|\le\frac{1}{2}\left[\;\left|\cot\left(\frac{\beta_n-\beta_{n-1}}{2}\right)-\cot\left(\frac{\beta_2-\beta_1}{2}\right)\right|+\\+\left|\cot\left(\frac{\beta_n-\beta_{n-1}}{2}\right)\right|+|\sin \beta_1|\left|\cot\left(\frac{\beta_2-\beta_1}{2}\right)\right|+|\cos\beta_1|+1\;\right]=\\=\frac{1}{2}\left[\;\cot\left(\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)-\cot\left(\frac{\beta_n-\beta_{n-1}}{2}\right)+\\+\cot\left(\frac{\beta_n-\beta_{n-1}}{2}\right)+\sin 0\cot\left(\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)+\cos0+1\;\right]=\\=1+\frac{1}{2}\cot\left(\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)<\frac{8}{3}\;,$

for all $\;n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}.$

Therefore,

$\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n \cos\left(h-\sqrt{h}\right)\right|<\frac{8}{3}\;,\;\;\text{ for all }\;n\in\mathbb{N}.$

And by applying the property $2$, we get that

$\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n \sin\beta_h\right|\le\frac{1}{2}\left[\;\left|\cot\left(\frac{\beta_n-\beta_{n-1}}{2}\right)-\cot\left(\frac{\beta_2-\beta_1}{2}\right)\right|+\\+\left|\cot\left(\frac{\beta_n-\beta_{n-1}}{2}\right)\right|+|\cos\beta_1|\left|\cot\left(\frac{\beta_2-\beta_1}{2}\right)\right|+|\sin\beta_1|+1\;\right]=\\=\frac{1}{2}\left[\;\cot\left(\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)-\cot\left(\frac{\beta_n-\beta_{n-1}}{2}\right)+\\+\cot\left(\frac{\beta_n-\beta_{n-1}}{2}\right)+\cos 0\cot\left(\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)+\sin 0+1\;\right]=\\=\frac{1}{2}+\cot\left(\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)<\frac{23}{6}\;,$

for all $\;n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}.$

Therefore,

$\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n \sin\left(h-\sqrt{h}\right)\right|<\frac{23}{6}\;,\;\;\text{ for all }\;n\in\mathbb{N}.$

---

**Corollary 2:**

$\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n \sin h\sin\sqrt{h}\right|<\frac{31}{12}<\frac{13}{5}\;,\;\;\text{ for all }\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;,$

$\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n \cos h\cos\sqrt{h}\right|<\frac{31}{12}<\frac{13}{5}\;,\;\;\text{ for all }\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;,$

$\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n \sin h\cos\sqrt{h}\right|<\frac{19}{6}<\frac{16}{5}\;,\;\;\text{ for all }\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;,$

$\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n \cos h\sin\sqrt{h}\right|<\frac{19}{6}<\frac{16}{5}\;,\;\;\text{ for all }\;n\in\mathbb{N}.$

**Proof:**

Using the results of Corollary 1, we get that

$\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n \sin h\sin\sqrt{h}\right|=\frac{1}{2}\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n \left[\cos\left(h-\sqrt{h}\right)-\cos\left(h+\sqrt{h}\right)\right]\right|=\\=\frac{1}{2}\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n\cos\left(h-\sqrt{h}\right)-\sum_\limits{h=1}^n\cos\left(h+\sqrt{h}\right)\right|\le\\\le\frac{1}{2}\left[\;\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n\cos\left(h-\sqrt{h}\right)\right|+\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n\cos\left(h+\sqrt{h}\right)\right|\;\right]<\\<\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{8}{3}+\frac{5}{2}\right]=\frac{31}{12}<\frac{13}{5}\;,\;\;\;\;\text{ for all }\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;,$

$\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n \cos h\cos\sqrt{h}\right|=\frac{1}{2}\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n \left[\cos\left(h+\sqrt{h}\right)+\cos\left(h-\sqrt{h}\right)\right]\right|=\\=\frac{1}{2}\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n\cos\left(h+\sqrt{h}\right)+\sum_\limits{h=1}^n\cos\left(h-\sqrt{h}\right)\right|\le\\\le\frac{1}{2}\left[\;\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n\cos\left(h+\sqrt{h}\right)\right|+\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n\cos\left(h-\sqrt{h}\right)\right|\;\right]<\\<\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{5}{2}+\frac{8}{3}\right]=\frac{31}{12}<\frac{13}{5}\;,\;\;\;\;\text{ for all }\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;,$

$\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n \sin h\cos\sqrt{h}\right|=\frac{1}{2}\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n \left[\sin\left(h+\sqrt{h}\right)+\sin\left(h-\sqrt{h}\right)\right]\right|=\\=\frac{1}{2}\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n\sin\left(h+\sqrt{h}\right)+\sum_\limits{h=1}^n\sin\left(h-\sqrt{h}\right)\right|\le\\\le\frac{1}{2}\left[\;\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n\sin\left(h+\sqrt{h}\right)\right|+\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n\sin\left(h-\sqrt{h}\right)\right|\;\right]<\\<\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{5}{2}+\frac{23}{6}\right]=\frac{19}{6}<\frac{16}{5}\;,\;\;\;\;\text{ for all }\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;,$

$\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n \cos h\sin\sqrt{h}\right|=\frac{1}{2}\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n \left[\sin\left(h+\sqrt{h}\right)-\sin\left(h-\sqrt{h}\right)\right]\right|=\\=\frac{1}{2}\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n\sin\left(h+\sqrt{h}\right)-\sum_\limits{h=1}^n\sin\left(h-\sqrt{h}\right)\right|\le\\\le\frac{1}{2}\left[\;\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n\sin\left(h+\sqrt{h}\right)\right|+\left|\sum_\limits{h=1}^n\sin\left(h-\sqrt{h}\right)\right|\;\right]<\\<\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{5}{2}+\frac{23}{6}\right]=\frac{19}{6}<\frac{16}{5}\;,\;\;\;\;\text{ for all }\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;.$

---

**Corollary 3:**

$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin 1\sin\sqrt{1}+\sin 2\sin\sqrt{2}+\sin 3\sin\sqrt{3}+\ldots+\sin n\sin\sqrt{n}}{n^\gamma}=0$

for any $\;\gamma>0.$

**Proof:**

Since $$-\frac{31}{12 n^\gamma}<\frac{\sum_\limits{h=1}^n \sin h\sin\sqrt{h}}{n^\gamma}<\frac{31}{12 n^\gamma}\;\;\;\;\text{ for all }\;n\in\mathbb{N}$$ and $\;\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\left(-\frac{31}{12 n^\gamma}\right)=0\;,\;\;\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{31}{12 n^\gamma}=0\;,$

by applying the squeeze theorem, we get that

$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}\frac{\sin 1\sin\sqrt{1}+\sin 2\sin\sqrt{2}+\sin 3\sin\sqrt{3}+\ldots+\sin n\sin\sqrt{n}}{n^\gamma}=0\;.$

Comment: If $a_n-a_{n-1}$ is an odd multiple of $\pi$, then $\cot\left(\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{2}\right)$ is zero and it improves the estimate. Anyway my approach is the same of Conrad’s but I have only taken into account the real part of the complex numbers.

Comment: Oops ... I missed the factor of $\frac12 $ in the argument.  Please accept my apology.

Comment: Since $\;2\pi k<a_n-a_{n-1}<2\pi+2\pi k$, then $\;\pi k<\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{2}<\pi+\pi k$, hence the function cotangent is defined for all $n\ge2$. Look at the hypothesis.

Comment: You are welcome. If you notice some mistake, please tell me it.

Comment: This looks good Angelo. With $a_n=n\pm \sqrt{n}$, we have for $n\ne1$ $$\frac12\left(a_n-a_{n-1}\right)=\frac12\left(1\pm\frac1{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n-1}}\right)$$

Comment: Indeed, in the property, I have written $n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}$.

Comment: @Mark, please, could you check what I wrote in my answer? If you find some mistake, let me know it. Could try to improve the estimates I got applying Conrad’s method?